# JavaScript call method is not working for OwlCarousel-Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, carousel

I'm currently facing a problem with Ruby on Rails inability to allow JavaScript elements to run. I tried just about everything to get this plugin working. Here's my current code/setup.

```
Application.js
//= require owl.carousel

Application.scss.css
*= require owl.carousel
*= require owl.theme

Markup
 <div class="row">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
                autoPlay: 3000,
                item : 3,
                itemsDesktop : [1119,3],
                itemsDesktopSmall : [979, 3]
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-2 columns mid-index-bg">
      <h2 style="color: red; text-align: center;">Carousel Placeholder</h2>
        <div class="owl-carousel">
            <div class="item"><%= image_tag 'Photos/pic1.jpg' %></div>
            <div class="item"><%= image_tag 'Photos/pic2.jpg' %></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `$('.owl-carousel')` and not `$('#owl-carousel')` as you're targeting an Id instead of a class

In jquery the selector `#` targets an ID  where a period `.` Targets a class name

Either change that or change
`<div class="owl-carousel">` 
To
`<div id="owl-carousel">`

And leave your javascript as is

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. That definitely was the problem.

Comment: @user3646743 accept the answer, if it has solved your Q.